# Does anyone know the .net odbc driver connection string for excel 2003's xml spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, odbc, connection-string

I know this has a certain "send me teh codes" quality, but the internet has really been letting me down on this one.  I have an excel file in excel 2003's xml format that I want to attach an odbc connection to.

And I can't seem to find the right connection string.  connectionstrings.com has let me down, and other questions here on SO (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269876/what-is-the-connection-string-for-odbc-connections)) also don't cover this file type.  And, of course, neither the binary xls connection nor the new xlsx connection seem to work?

Does anyone out there know the right syntax?  IS there an odbc driver for excel 2003 xml?

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=C:\MyExcel.xls;DefaultDir=c:\mypath;